# VSCode cant run .net core api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I created an an API application using .NET Core on VS Code.
I type `dotnet run` in the terminal and its result is shown in the below pic:
[image]

but when I browse URL in browser it shows:
[image]

what should I do? I changed the port but not work yet.

this is my StartUp:

```cs
namespace API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            // services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            // {
            //     c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
            // });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                // app.UseSwagger();
                // app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my program.cs:

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the code, the default route of API controller may look like this `Route("api/[controller]")`, which does not include `[action]` token in attribute route.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET /api/values
    [HttpGet] 
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Data From Get Action");
    }

    // GET /api/values/3
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }

    // POST /api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        return Ok("Data From Post Action");
    }
}
```

To access the first action, you can make request with following URL.

```
https://localhost:5001/api/values
```

Besides, if you really want to match `/api/values/get` to your endpoint, you can try to modify the code as below.

```
// GET /api/values/get
[HttpGet("get")] 
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("Data From Get Action");
}
```